# How do i get the smallest and highest value of a string?

Tags: swift, string, sorting

```
let smallestgrade = (min(musicgrade, bildgrade, matematicsgrade))  (Dosent work)
```

The alternatives of grades are: "A,B,C,D,E,F"

F is the smallest value and has a value of 0

A is the biggest value and has a value of 20

how do I sort out the smallest value?
Can I do something like this:

A = 20

B = 17.5

C = 15.0

D = 12.5

E = 10

F = 0

??

Comment: This looks like some kind of homework/assignment, if this is the case you should do some more research. this is a fairly easy thing to achieve. what have you tried already?

Comment: How does it "not work"? What is the input and expected output? – You *can* call min() and max() with a list of strings...

Comment: not an homework assignment just me coding

Comment: I can´t call min() with a string because a string dose´t have a value yet. How do i give grades values? ex let A = 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, type safe solution:

```
enum Grade : Double {
    case A = 20.0
    case B = 17.5
    case C = 15.0
    case D = 12.5
    case E = 10.0
    case F = 0.0
}

extension Grade : Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: Grade, rhs: Grade) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}

let musicGrade = Grade.A
let bildGrade = Grade.E
let mathGrade = Grade.D

let worstGrade = [musicGrade, bildGrade, mathGrade].min()
print(worstGrade)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want this sort of thing:

```
let gradeValues = ["A" : 20, "B" : 17.5, "C" : 15.0, "D" : 12.5, "E" : 10, "F" : 0]
let grades = ["B", "A", "C", "A", "B"]
let minim = grades.min {gradeValues[$0]! < gradeValues[$1]!} // "C"
```

Comment: `let minim = grades.max()` happens to produce the same result :)

Comment: @MartinR Sure, but the key word is "happens to". What if we introduce "A+" and "C-" options? What if, what if, what if? I could go on. The fact is that the question is about the need for a correspondence between the letter-based _symbols_ and their numeric _meanings_, and that correspondence is what my solution demonstrates.

Comment: You are of course right – my remark applies only to the special case mentioned in the question.

Comment: It worked out thanks guys!